# How to give default value to a combobox in orca?

Tags: combobox, windows-installer, setup-project, setup-deployment, orca

I have created a combobox in orca but I'm unable to give a default value to the combobox, btw the combobox is in replacement of a checkbox control and I have also tried changing the default value in the property table of orca. Please let me know if there is any other method as the above is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Installer doesn't have a "default value" concept for the combobox.  You would have to have a set property custom action to set the property to the value (Not text) of what you want to be default if the property does not already have a value  ( Not PROPERTY ).